# Extract HTML at XPath of HTML file

Tags: java, parsing, html-parsing, htmlunit, htmlcleaner

I'm trying get get the html code from a file at a given Xpath.  I tried using HTMLUnit, but it doesn't seem to play too nicely with these static files downloaded from google cache.  I've had a bit better luck with HTMLCleaner, but so far I've just been able to get text and no HTML code.  Any suggestions would be helpful.  The following is the code I am currently using.

```
TagNode tagNode = new HtmlCleaner().clean(readFile(htmlCacheFile));
Document doc = new DomSerializer(new CleanerProperties()).createDOM(tagNode);

XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String title = ((String) xpath.evaluate(TITLE_XPATH, doc, XPathConstants.STRING)).trim();
String body =  ((String) xpath.evaluate(BODY_XPATH, doc, XPathConstants.STRING)).trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a Java solution? What you want to do is perfectly possible with a site scraper running in a headless browser. [PhantomJs](http://phantomjs.org/) is a headless WebKit, which allows you to execute JavaScript/CoffeeScript on a web page. I think it could help you solve your issue.

[Pjscrape](http://nrabinowitz.github.com/pjscrape/) is a useful [web scraping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping) tool based on PhantomJs.

Here is an example (**config.js**), which logs to the console (also possible to file):

```
pjs.addSuite({
  url: 'http://stackoverflow.com/',
  noConflict: true,
  scraper: function() {
    var html = _pjs.$('body').html();
    return html;
  }
});
```

To start it with `phantomjs pjscrape.js config.js`

Results in:

```
* Suite 0 starting
* Opening http://stackoverflow.com/
* Scraping http://stackoverflow.com/
* Suite 0 complete
* Writing 1 items
["\n    <noscript>&lt;div id=\"noscript-padding\"&gt;&lt;/div&gt;</noscript>\n    <div id=\"notify-container\"></div>\n    <div id=\"overlay-header\"></div>\n    <div id=\"custom-header\"></div>\n\n    <div class=\"container\">\n        <div id=\"header\">\n            <div id=\"portalLink\">\n                <a class=\"genu\" onclick=\"StackExchange.ready(function(){genuwine.click();});return false;\">Stack Exchange</a>\n   

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this help. In the link below there is XPath example and JSoup solution of the same problem. If you are familiar with CSS selectors or not(there is plenty methods for parsing, cleaning etc.)use jsoup which is very powerful library for html parsing. If I understand the goal is to get body and title from the file.

My solution for this problem is:

```
Document webpage = Jsoup.parse(new File("file.html"), "UTF-8");
System.out.println(webpage.title()+" "+webpage.body().html());
```

https://norrisshelton.wordpress.com/2011/01/27/jsoup-java-html-parser/